# How should I setup DNS when all I have is a VPS with a static IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver

I have a VPS with a static IP and a domain pointed to the registrants nameservers, so I can change all of the DNS records.

In past, I've always just set nameservers to my VPS/hosting provider, but I can't do that now. All I have is a static IP for the server.

**The question is, how should I configure the domain to point to the VPS?** Is it enough if I just set a A record with the IP address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a **DNS hosting service provider** [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service) for your domain.

I recommend you to try out a service like [**FreeDNS**](http://freedns.afraid.org/).  Free for most use. You can find more *free* dns providers [**here**](http://wiki.lowendbox.com/doku.php?id=free-dns-providers).

1. Register an account at your new dns provider
2. Create a new zone for your domain (eg. `mydomain.tld`)
3. Add a A-Record that points to your Server-IP (e.g. `A: * / 127.0.0.1`)
4. Point your domain to the nameserver's provided by FreeDNS

Please note, that it will take 24 – 48 hours before your nameserver info propagates to the rest of the world.

Comment: My domain registrar offers to create and manage DNS zone, so I guess it doesn't matter where I create the A-record as long as I have set correct nameservers right?

Comment: you need to point your domain to the nameservers given by your DNS hosting service provider, to resolve the zones.

Answer (score 1):

Who's DNS servers you use are not too important. If your registrar provides DNS, I would just use theirs.

Wherever you host, you need to:

1) Create A records to point your domain to your VPS's IP address.

2) Make sure that at the registrar the nameservers listed match those where you have decided to use.

3) Once done, run your domain through something like http://www.intodns.com/ to make sure you have it right.

Answer (score 0):

For most purposes (including website hosting) it's enough to create only A record. If you want to receive incoming emails - specify MX record.